# Python regex finding phrases in same line

Tags: python, regex

I have transcripts like this:

```
speaker1 (caller): hello.
speaker2 (agent): thank you for calling. 
speaker1 (caller): I need some help with my account 3429.
speaker2 (agent): Sure let me help.
```

They are of the form 'speakerN (caller or agent)'. I need to write a regex to get lists of caller and agent conversations. So for the above example, I would output:

```
['(caller): hello. ', '(agent): thank you for calling', '(caller): I need some help with my account 3429.', '(agent): Sure let me help.']
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
aList = re.findall('speaker. (.*) speaker.|$', transcript)
print(aList)
```

I know there's a speakerN in the front, some text that I need to capture, and then either another speakerN at the end (indicating a new list) or the end of line. This is the logic that I tried to capture, but it's putting the entire transcript in the one list element and an empty string in the second. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `re.findall(r'\(.*', s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex only produces non-overlapping matches. So you can't have `speaker` occuring twice in your pattern. You need to put it inside a lookahead:

```
speaker\d+ (\([^(]*?)(?=\s+speaker\d+|$)
```

This will capture the text in group 1.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/kY1bQ1/1)

Comment: What does the `[^(]` part accomplish? Isn't the literal parentheses that occurs in '(caller)' or '(agent)' already encoded in the `\(` preceding it?

Comment: @user3004041 Yes, `\(` matches a paren. `[^(]` matches anything _but_ a paren.

Answer (score 0):

use `aList = re.findall('speaker\d+\s(.*?)(?=\sspeaker|$)', transcript)`

`.*?` will stop matching right away when it finds another occurrence of speaker, while `.*` will keep matching any character till the last occurrence. Hope it helps.

Edit: speaker\d+, . will match only one character.

Edit: not good if word 'speaker' comes in between conversation. So use

`aList = re.findall('speaker\d+\s*(.*?)(?=\sspeaker\s*\(|$)', transcript)`